# Does it make sense to have multimodule golang repo just so people will not have to import my library just for it's types

Tags: go

I am writing a library to simplify stream processing, the library exposes interfaces so that people can write plugins and middleware. The problem with this is some of the interfaces use concrete types defined in the library and this forces people to import my library just for it's types. I was thinking if it is a good idea to keep all my types and interfaces in a separate package with it's own go.mod file so that people can just import the types package without having to pull in the entire library.

```golang
package ziggurat

import "context"

type Handler interface {
    HandleEvent(event Event) ProcessStatus
}

type Streams interface {
    Consume(ctx context.Context, handler Handler) chan error
}

type StructuredLogger interface {
    Info(message string, kvs ...map[string]interface{})
    Debug(message string, kvs ...map[string]interface{})
    Warn(message string, kvs ...map[string]interface{})
    Error(message string, err error, kvs ...map[string]interface{})
    Fatal(message string, err error, kvs ...map[string]interface{})
}

type Event interface {
    Value() []byte
    Context() context.Context
    Header(key string) string
}
```

To implement the Handler interface people will have to use the `Event` interface and this requires them to pull in the entire library.

Comment: And the "entire library" is so huge that importing it might be of concern? Or what is your worry? How many bytes will the user save by importing a types-only package as opposed to the entire package?

Comment: My library internally uses the confluent kafka library which is pretty heavy.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense to have multimodule golang repo just so people will not have to import my library just for it's types [?]

No.